# D365 Emails stuck in pending send status

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

We experience in Dynamics 365 Customer Service a problem, that all Emails which were previously send out without any problems, are now stuck in "pending send" status. We also experienced trouble with email synchronization of incoming emails. This problem was solved after 3h automatically. But the problem with sending emails from the CRM still exists.

Anyone who experiences the same Problem?

We think that it may be a problem which directly comes from Microsoft. It may be connected to some server problems with the sandbox server from Microsoft. But this is just a guess.

We tried almost everything we could, but we can't to much on the D365 Online version of CRM. A Service ticket was created, but we still wait for a respond from microsoft.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you checked about the storage of the email box?

Comment: @Stefen configure the mailbox again for the User. sometime this issues got resolved with this actions

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but it was a server problem on Microsofts side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A server problem on the Microsofts end caused this email problem. Not all but a lot of environments in europe were concerned.

[image]